# Como fazer espessura da borda responsiva para essa Bandeira do Brasil feita com CSS?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Eu estou tentando fazer uma bandeira do brasil que seja responsiva. Porém me deparei com um problema com a faixa branca da bandeira.
 ***OBS:*** não vou colocar o texto na faixa!

O que acontece é que a faixa na verdade é um `border`, porém eu não posso usar valor em `%` como `border-width`. Então quando **a bandeira diminui a borda fica grossa**, e conforme **a bandeira cresce a borda fica fina**... Como corrijo isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso corrigir isso pra minha borda também ficar responsiva junto com o restante da bandeira? 
Como posso fazer uma borda responsiva? 
Ou existe alguma outra técnica que posso usar sem ser a borda?

Segue o código.

```css
.bandeira {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(circle at 55% 35%, rgba(255,255,255,.85) 0%, transparent 1%),
    radial-gradient(circle, navy 25%, transparent 26%),
    linear-gradient(-30deg, green 30%, transparent 31%, transparent 70%, green 71%),
    linear-gradient(30deg, green 30%, gold 31%, gold 70%, green 71%);
}

.faixa {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 55%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.faixa::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: -70%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bandeira">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="faixa"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mudar o tamanho da borda com media query é uma opção, se não, retirar a borda e usar uma div com height baseado no `vw` ou algo assim

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam com media query eu vou ter "saltos" na espessura, pois ficaria tipo uma largura entre 320px e 768px, depois outra largura entre 768px e 992px... seria mudanças "secas" e não algo fluido como é o restante da bandeira. Repare que como ela é toda em % vc não tem "saltos" nos tamanhos. Com medidas em VH ou VW a bandeira pode deformar dependendo do aspect-ratio da tela do dispositivo não? Tipo em um monitor ultra-wide, ou um celular na vertical...

Comment: da pra colocar várias media query e não ter esses saltos, da muito trabalho mas funciona, se usar JS da pra fazer no evento de resize da tela, ai fica um pouco mais simples. _"Com medidas em VH ou VW a bandeira pode deformar dependendo do aspect-ratio da tela do dispositivo não?"_ isso já não sei dizer

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam para ficar fluido acho que teria que trocar os PX da borda pelo menos a cada 5 ou 10px. Então se sua janela diminuir 10px de largura vc tem que mudar a borda para `N`px... acredito não ser uma opção muito viável, apesar de que pode ser que de certo sim... mas acho que só com CSS deve ter alguma maneira mais prática

Comment: Faz a bandeira da Itália que é mais fácil rs :D

Comment: Tio @Sam http://weknowmemes.com/generator/uploads/generated/g1473323967676269521.jpg  Mas amanha vou perguntar como faz a do Japão então :p

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de usar a propriedade `border` completa, use apenas o `border-radius` e coloque um `background` branco no `::before` da faixa (desta forma a espessura da faixa não fica presa ao `px` fixo da borda), e será criado um círculo branco que será uma parte da faixa.

Agora crie outro pseudo `::after` igual ao `::before`, só que com um fundo azul do círculo que ficará por cima do branco, aumentando um pouco o `top` e o `left`, fazendo o efeito da faixa. Como agora os valores são todos em `%` ficará 100% responsivo.

Retirei a propriedade `box-sizing: border-box` que já não é necessária. Para dar uma compensada no "blur" da borda do círculo azul, alterei o `transparent` de `26%` para `27%`.

Código:

```css
.bandeira {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(circle at 55% 35%, rgba(255,255,255,.85) 0%, transparent 1%),
    radial-gradient(circle, navy 25%, transparent 27%),
    linear-gradient(-30deg, green 30%, transparent 31%, transparent 70%, green 71%),
    linear-gradient(30deg, green 30%, gold 31%, gold 70%, green 71%);
}

.faixa {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 55%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.faixa::before, .faixa::after{
   content: "";
   width: 200%;
   height: 200%;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: absolute;
}

.faixa::before {
   background: #fff;
   top: 30%;
   left: -70%;
}

.faixa::after {
   background: navy;
   top: 35%;
   left: -72%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bandeira">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="faixa"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Legal Sam, é uma abordagem que resolve. Mesmo não sendo um `border` responsivo, quebra o galho!

Comment: Acho que o único jeito é evitar borda, já que, até onde sei, não existe borda responsiva.